ConvNetSharp package - Performance
I am using ConvNetSharp package for one of the applications. This application is time critical, so I used Classify2DDemo program on my machine for net.Forward functionality, to see how it performs. It takes around 6 to 7 msec to predict a single input on my machine and configuration of my machine is below.

CPU-2.6 GHz
RAM 16 GB
Win-11
64 Bit OS
NVIDEA - GeForce GTX 1650 Ti

In my application, I would like to bring down the prediction time from 7msec to 2 msec so my questions are:

What standard configurations are needed to run net.Forward functionality of Classify2DDemo program optimally?
What are the options I have to bring down the processing time from 7 msec to 2 msec?

EDIT:
Thanks a lot for your response. Regarding software, I want to quickly get few details verified. I am using ConvNetSharp package for signal processing (not for images processing). I am working on EEG data processing where I have "4 electrodes" in my headband. I am capturing a "500 samples epoch" from each electrode at a time. I have such 3000+ epochs collected at different times. I am training the neural network based on this data. I have designed the neural network as follows:
using ConvNetSharp.Core.Training;
using ConvNetSharp.Core;
using ConvNetSharp.Core.Layers.Double;
using System;
using ConvNetSharp.Volume;
using ConvNetSharp.Volume.Double;


public class CNNModelTraining
{
    public const int iterations = 40;
    public const int featureNumber = 2000;
    public const int featuresWithLabels = 2001;

    public CNNModelTraining()
    {
        BuilderInstance<double>.Volume = new VolumeBuilder();
    }
    public ConvNetSharp.Core.Net<double> CreateCNNNetwork()
    {
        ConvNetSharp.Core.Net<double> net1 = new Net<double>();

        net1.AddLayer(new InputLayer(500, 4, 1));
        net1.AddLayer(new ConvLayer(5, 2, 20) { Stride = 2, Pad = 0 });
        net1.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());
        net1.AddLayer(new PoolLayer(2, 1));
        net1.AddLayer(new ConvLayer(3, 1, 30) { Stride = 2, Pad = 0 });
        net1.AddLayer(new ReluLayer());
        //net1.AddLayer(new PoolLayer(3, 1));
        net1.AddLayer(new FullyConnLayer(3));
        net1.AddLayer(new SoftmaxLayer(3));

        return net1;
    }

    public TrainerBase<double> GetTrainerForNetwork(Net<double> paramNet)
    {
        return new AdamTrainer<double>(paramNet) { LearningRate = 0.00003, BatchSize = 30 };
    }

    public static void TrainModel(double[][] jaggedBalancedData, double[][] outputArray, TrainerBase<double> trainerParam, ConvNetSharp.Core.Net<double> net1Param)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting to train the network ...");

        Console.WriteLine(outputArray.GetLength(0));
        Console.WriteLine(jaggedBalancedData.GetLength(0));

        var netx = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(500, 4, 1, jaggedBalancedData.GetLength(0)));
        var hotLabels = BuilderInstance.Volume.SameAs(new Shape(1, 1, 1, outputArray.GetLength(0)));

        for (var ix = 0; ix < outputArray.GetLength(0); ix++)   //Swati
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ix} {(int)outputArray[ix][0]}");

            hotLabels.Set(0, 0, 0, ix, (int)outputArray[ix][0]);

            for (var featureGrp = 0; featureGrp < 4; ++featureGrp)
            {
                for (int features = 0; features < 500; ++features)
                    netx.Set(features, featureGrp, 0, ix, jaggedBalancedData[ix][features + (featureGrp * 500)]);
            }
        }

        for (var iters = 0; iters < CNNModelTraining.iterations; iters++)
        {
            trainerParam.Train(netx, hotLabels);
            Console.WriteLine(trainerParam.Loss);
        }

    }

}



I would like to know if, the design of InputLayer (500, 4, 1) is correct to process a single data sample? Will the C# library internally take care of processing it in "4 chunks of 500 samples" or "500 chunks of 4 samples"? If the later is true, then I will do very wrong training and I will get very wrong predictions.
If I design my first ConvLayer as (5, 2, 20), will it process all 4 electrodes? OR I have to necessarily specify it as (5, 4, 20) to process all of them?
The pooling layer is an "average pooling layer" or a "max pooling layer"?

First thing first, managed languages are not suited for "time-critical" / real-time applications (because of the GC and JIT which can take far more than 7 ms alone). Your (low-end) GPU is not designed from AI/ANN stuff but for game. Also note that "CPU-2.6 GHz" gives no information (the 20-years-old CPUs reaching 4 GHz was far slower than current one). The CPU architecture and the number of core matters far more than frequency. On the software side, critical details are missing to really help you.

@jérôme-richard, I have edited my post to incorporate my software and consequently a few queries. It would be of great help if you could answer them. Thanks in advance.
